# How to get aggregation of child collection in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-aggregation

I have a data structure like this:

```
{
  "_id": "order1",
  "transactions": [
    {
      "amount": 100,
      "type": "payment"
    },
    {
      "amount": -10,
      "type": "refund"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to get sum of amount which is 100+(-10) = 90. I am new to mongodb. Can someone help me write query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use aggregate with `$unwind`

```
.aggregate([
{$unwind:"$transactions"},
{$group: {_id:"$_id", total: {$sum: "$transactions.amount"}}}
])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> db.aaa.aggregate([{$unwind:"$transactions"},{$group:{_id:null, total:{$sum:"$transactions.amount"}}}])
{ "_id" : null, "total" : 90 }
```